# Is the flow of charges in inductor though electric field zero?

Tags: electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, electric-fields, inductance

How electric field inside the wire of an inductor is zero (i.e. material of which loop is made — note material is assumed to be a superconductor), then how electrons flow in an inductor if electric field inside wire of inductor is zero?

This question struck in my mind when I was applying Faraday's law to circuit having an inductor. Please explain in LR circuit.

[Professor Walter Lewin video](https://youtu.be/cZN0AyNR4Kw).

*In this video professor Walter Lewin says that electric field would be zero but does not explain it in detail and also does not explain about  how charges flow when electric field is zero. It may  be better if you watch this video before answering my doubt*

Comment: There's nothing special about an inductor that makes current flow through it even though the E-field inside the wire is zero. This applies to an ordinary block or wire made of a "superconductor". If the E-field weren't zero, since the resistance of the material is zero, the current would increase indefinitely as long as this E-field is maintained.

Comment: Please fix your caps key and don’t SHOUT at us...

Comment: @Solar Mike Hi,who is shouting here?

Comment: @Unique just because tou are late to the party... check the edits...